# How to have the correct result from xml, xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to try this example:

File: Data.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="Transform.xslt"?>
<addressbook>
  <address>
    <first-name>Doris</first-name>
    <last-name>Smith</last-name>
    <city>New York</city>
    <state>WI</state>
  </address>
  <address>
    <first-name>Mary</first-name>
    <last-name>Smith</last-name>
    <city>Vancouver</city>
    <state>MA</state>
  </address>
```

File: Transform.xslt

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:text>Customers grouped by state&#xA;&#xA;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="/addressbook/address" group-by="state">
      <xsl:sort select="state"/>
      <xsl:text>  State = </xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
      <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
      <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
        <xsl:text>&#x9;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="(first-name, last-name)" separator=" "/>
        <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="city"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The expected Output is:

```
Customers grouped by state

  State = MA
  Mary Smith, Vancouver
  State = WI
  Doris Smith, New York
```

But what I have is:

Doris Smith New York WI Mary Smith Vancouver MA

I would be very grateful if you could  explain to me the problem.

Comment: If you're trying to use a browser to process your XSLT (which is what it looks like based on the `xml-stylesheet` processing instruction), you're not going to be able to use XSLT 2.0 (which means you can't use `xsl:for-each-group`; you'll have to use [Muenchian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html)).

Comment: Good job on the XSLT 2.0 though. It does give the expected result when using a 2.0 processor. (http://xsltransform.net/bFWR5Eu)

Comment: You're basically seeing the text in the original XML without the markup, which strongly suggests that the problem is in the way you invoke (or fail to invoke) the transformation rather than in the XSLT code itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you're using a browser to process your XSLT based on the `xml-stylesheet` processing instruction in your XML file.

Unfortunately, without something like [Saxon-CE](http://www.saxonica.com/ce/index.xml) or [Saxon-JS](http://www.saxonica.com/saxon-js/index.xml) you're not going to be able to run XSLT 2.0 transforms in the browser.

Here's an XSLT 1.0 option that uses [Muenchian Grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) that should work...

**XML Input**

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="Transform.xslt"?>
<addressbook>
    <address>
    <first-name>Doris</first-name>
    <last-name>Smith</last-name>
    <city>New York</city>
    <state>WI</state>
  </address>
    <address>
    <first-name>Mary</first-name>
    <last-name>Smith</last-name>
    <city>Vancouver</city>
    <state>MA</state>
  </address>
</addressbook>
```

**XSLT 1.0** (Transform.xslt)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:key name="address" match="address" use="state"/>

  <xsl:template match="/addressbook">
    <xsl:text>Customers grouped by state&#xA;&#xA;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="address[count(.|key('address',state)[1])=1]">
      <xsl:sort select="state"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="concat('&#x9;',state,'&#xA;')"/>
      <xsl:for-each select="key('address',state)">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('&#x9;',
          first-name,' ',last-name,
          ', ',city,'&#xA;')"/>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
Customers grouped by state

    MA
    Mary Smith, Vancouver
    WI
    Doris Smith, New York
```